# ASP.NET MVC: Use existing Account or create new User controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm creating a new ASP.NET MVC application.  So far I've used the Account controller for actions related to a user's account -- Login/Logout, Activation (like Register, but I use Register for other actions in the site so I've renamed it), Add/Update Contact information. Up to now, though, I've been concentrating on the administrative user views.

I'm at the point where I'm going to start creating the various views that non-administrative users will see.  These are rather limited compared to the administrative interface.   My inclination is to create a new set of views and associated controller in the User "family" instead of using the Account views/controller.  Is this a good idea or should I stick with the Account controller?  My feeling is that since this is for ordinary users it should be a separate controller since Account would apply to both ordinary and administrative users.

**EDIT**: After reading the first couple of responses, my refactored question is:

Do you consider the Account controller to be for administrative actions related to the user's account or for all actions on the user's account?  Would you distinguish between membership/role related views/data and application related views/data to the extent of creating a new controller.

Related, but doesn't directly answer my question: [ASP.NET MVC Account Controller usage guidelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237249/asp-net-mvc-account-controller-usage-guidelines)

Comment: tvanfosson *asking* an MVC question?! Wow. If I were you, I'd just wait for tvanfosson to answer, since he usually answers MVC questions first  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a right or wrong answer here, so I'll give you my opinion.

Technically, either solution (extending the Account controller or creating a new controller) will work just fine.

So I think this is more a question of how the users perceive the functionality. I think it's a good idea to follow the convention that the URI dictates the controller (or vice versa, if you prefer).

If, for example, you'd like to have the "administrative" actions on a separate path, then that should be a separate controller. You might want to do this, for example, if you use an IIS module for authentication or if it makes your log analysis easier.

On the other hand, it might be the case that the users perceive account functions and administrative functions as part of the same family of actions, except that some users have additional features. If so, then that suggests that should be on the same path in the URI and, hence, part of the same controller.

Summing up, I think this is a question you should ask your user representative instead of folks on this site. :)

**Update**: Regarding your updated question, I would say that it is fairly natural to put an action for changing a user's password on the Account controller, and that action could be invoked by the user herself, not just an administrator. So I wouldn't presume that the Account controller is strictly for administrative tasks. On the other hand, your example of the fund-raising performance is well outside of the scope of membership-related things, so it is not clear that it belongs on Account, either. I'm still leaning towards, "ask your user representative."

Comment: I think what I'm after is whether people consider the Account controller to be for administrative actions or for all actions related to an account.  In my scenario I want to show the person their current fund-raising status for the most recent event they've registered for as the index view.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC you will usually create controls based on data types rather than access types. For example:

Instead of 2 /Controllers/UsersControl.cs and /Controllers/Admin/UsersControls.cs it is easier to use one common controller for both admins and regular users - /Controllers/UsersController.cs (by setting different [Authorize] attributes and views).

I would keep existing AccountController.cs for encapsulating account related functionality. And just add new UsersController.cs for the rest Users related functionality (which could have methods like OnlineUsers etc.)